# Compute the closure of graph of function from complement of hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

I'm hoping someone can give me some tips to help speed up computation on the following problem:

Suppose I have a map $G=(g_1/f,\dots,g_m/f):\mathbb{A}^n\setminus{V(f)}\to \mathbb{A}^m$. I'm interested in computing the closure of the graph of $G$. So using e.g. Macaulay2 I would use:

$$G^\#:\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]\to \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n,t]/(ft-1), x_i\mapsto x_i, y_i\mapsto g_it$$
and compute the kernel of this map.

My first question is this:

> Obviously $(fy_1-g_1,\dots,fy_m-g_m)\subset \ker G^\#$. Assume that $(f_i,g)=1$ for all $i$. Do we then have an equality here?

An affirmative answer would of course make the computation using Macaulay2 completely redundant. So if the answer is negative, I wonder:

> What is a good guess for an efficient monomial order in this situation?

Right now I think that some lex order with $x_1<\dots<x_n<y_1<\dots<y_m$ might be most efficient, but I'm not very experienced in this kind of thing so this is really nothing more then a hunch.

---

Edit: the answer to the first question is no. This can be verified easily using computer algebra packages, as I probably should have done before asking the question here.

Comment: I seem to recall that you need to saturate with respect to $f$